# OAuth process, Twitter, and Readability

Tags: api, twitter, oauth, readability

From what I can tell, Twitter and Readability differ in the order of the OAuth process. [Twitter requires](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api#oauth):

1. request_token
2. authorize / authenticate
3. access_token

whilst [Readability](http://www.readability.com/developers/api) requires:

1. authorize
2. request_token
3. access_token

Meanwhile, the [OAuth spec](http://oauth.net/core/diagram.png) states that the twitter flow is the correct one. Am I missing something, or has readability got this the wrong way round?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Readability documentation, I think they were just lazy in how they wrote it. The request token is useless if you've already authorized, so I believe they just put the URLs in the incorrect order.